# How to arrange input elements to columns or other way to improve form readability

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

Order entry form is created from fields defined in database.
Every field contains text caption and input element.

input element is input type=text, checkbox or select element.
If can be also jquery ui autocomplete or datepicker containing dropdown button in right side.
JQuery UI is used.

In output input elements are not aligned. It looks messy:

[image: messy form]

How to improve readability of this layout?

How to align left sides of input elements vertically so that they start at same column ?
if browser window is resized, new column should appear or removed automatically.

Maybe there is some magic css or jquery ui feature which allows this?
Also it may be possible to make all field widths the same. Minimum width of each input element 
is defined in database. Rendered width can be somewhat bigger. For captions, it is possible to make two pass rendering: in first pass find maximum number of characters in caption and calclulate width for every caption.

html used is:

```
<form id='_form' class='form-fields'>

<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='Klient0_nimi'><u>Customer</u></label>
<span id='span_Klient0_nimi'><input id='Klient0_nimi' name='Klient0_nimi'  style='width:100px'  class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' maxlength='80'  lookup='Klient' value='Brad Abrams' ></input>
<button type='button' class='form-combobutton' tabindex=-1 ></button>
</span>
</div>

<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='Tasudok'>Number</label>
<input class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'  id='Tasudok' name='Tasudok' value='798'  style='width:100px'  maxlength='25' />
</div>

<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='Kuupaev'>Date</label>
<input maxlength=10 size=10 class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'  id='Kuupaev' name='Kuupaev'   value='1/26/2012' />
</div>


<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='Maksetin1_tingimus'><u >Condition</u></label>
<span><select id='Maksetin1_tingimus' name='Maksetin1_tingimus' class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' style='width:100px'  
 lookup='Maksetin' value='10' >

 <option value=''></option>
 <option value='10'>10 days</option>
 </select>
</span>
</div>


<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='Eimuuda'>No change</label>
<input type='hidden' value='false' name='Eimuuda' />
<input type='checkbox' id='Eimuuda' name='Eimuuda'/>
</div>

<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='Doksumma'>Total</label><input style='text-align:right'  id='Doksumma' name='Doksumma'  disabled='disabled' class='jqgrid-readonlycolumn' readonly='readonly' tabindex='-1'  value='0.00'  style='width:100px'  maxlength='0' />
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: you could use CSS to assign fixed width to form-field class. That should do the trick

Comment: I want input and select elements inside form-field divs to be left aligned. setting fixed width to form-field does to allow this since caption widths are different in every form-field. Also I do'nt know how to calculate max width from caption texts. Should I multiply max caption lenght to some magical constant ant use it as px value.

Comment: @Andrus I updated my answer to handle horizontal resize. check the updated html. Now the form is 2up (4 columns), but you can do same thing with 3up (6 columns), or more.

Comment: Thank you. It looks that best way would be to allow any number or column by increment of 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8 or 9 . It seems that using this dis in your code can contain only single table cell. This makes table element usage useless and it can removed which leads to the html in question. How to avoid hard coded caption width 100 px ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some column alignment: on the first columns the labels, on the second column the input fields.

Eventually you can use 4 column: labels on 1st and 3rd, input fields on 2nd and 3rd.

Also, use width:100% on input fields. And you may want to consider text-align:right for labels.

The old html table may help you here.

As you have many fields you may want to consider to split the form in sections; like using `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp)

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    .lbl {
        text-align: right;
        width: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .fld {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .frm {
        display: inline-block;
    }

</style>
</head>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        <div class="frm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="fld" id="name" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="fld" id="email" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="dob">Date of birth:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="fld" id="dob" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="frm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="addr">Address:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="fld" id="addr" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="city">City:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="fld" id="city" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="ctry">Country:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="fld" id="ctry" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This would be the results:

when there is enough space horizontally:

[image]

when there is not enough space horizontally:

[image]

Comment: It should work from tablet screens to wide LCD screens: If browser window is resized, input fields in forms should automatically wrap to next/previous row to fit window width. Columns should appear or disapper automatically.  You recommend using fixed number of columns. How to implement automatic form layout change in this case?

Comment: If browser window is resized, your example does not resize: it still contains same number of columns. How to make columns appear or disappear so that as much form-field divs as possible appear in row? Only last row can contain fewer elements.

Comment: you can put the `<form>` in a table, then put two tables side-by-side, when the screen is wide enough the two tables would be displayed side-by-side, if the screen is not big enough, the two table will go one under the other.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like your sample does not allow more than 2 columns. If the screen is wide enough for 3 or 4 or 5 columns , 3  or 4 or 5 columns should appear. How to fix this ?

Comment: Of course you can add more columns, adding more `<div class="frm">` sections, with nested tables. I this sample I put only two, but you can add as much sections as you want.

Comment: Thank you. It looks that this leads to `frm` divs each contining table with single input element. It this case table element does not have any benefits. It can removed and we get the same html as in question. Your answer has hard coded 100px constant. Rendering engine knows only number of characters in captions. Captions are user defined and are in language which can selected at runtime. 100px may not be sufficient for some forms. How to remove 100px constant or calculate it in runtime and add it to dynamically created style?

Comment: You can remove the constant 100px just by removing it: it works anyway. Just try that: cut the sample and paste it here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro.
Doing that you will lose some alignment when in column view, btw.

Comment: Thank you. I removed width: 100px and put every input field to separate table to allow any number of columns. Result it the same as image in question: input fields are `not` left aligned. How to make input fields left aligned in column and allow any number or columns by increment of 1 depending on window width without hard coded constants in css or how to calculate those hard coded constants ?

Comment: the 100px is used to make sure things are aligned (same width); you may find a way to calculate the labels width with some magic; I can't help there, sorry.

Comment: I posted this as separate question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047195/how-to-replace-fixed-values-in-resposible-form-css

Answer (score 1):

You can use table instead of using div.
make 6 columns or as much you requied.

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
             <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
             <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td> 
            <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
             <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
             <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td> 
            <td style="width: 20%;">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Form can be rendered with different browser window widths from tablet computers to 1600 x 2600 lcd screens. Number of columns should determined automatically and it shoudl change dynamically if browser window is resized. How to implement such responsible layout using table element ?

Comment: I have edited it. Please insert your contains betweend the <td> tag

Comment: Thank you. Using this for mobile screen columns do not wrap to multiple lines. How to fors columns to wrap to multiple lines if there is not enough room for all columns ?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "Responsive design" solution. This is commonly achieved using a grid based style sheet such as this very simple and straightforward 12 columnn grid http://cssgrid.net/

You should also right align your labels, not left align them  (i.e. like Luigi's answer)

Do not use tables for layout.  Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: Well, label alignment is mostly a matter of taste, there is no right or wrong choice. Some people also prefer labels on top, ar label at the bottom. Some others, put the label inside the input fields as well :)
`Do not use tables for layout. Tables are for tabular data.` a long time ago, tables were used to arrange elements, now they say that CSS is right and tables are wrong, I think that tables are great for layouting forms, btw, still they grant the best control over how your form is arranged.

Comment: @Luig, actually there are good reasons to use right alignment - if you consider accessibility issues, particularly users with low vision that have to use screen magnifiers. The closer the label is to the input field, the easier it is for a user using very high screen magnification to navigate your forms. without getting lost in lots of white space between the label and the field.

Comment: +1, btw, there is a long (and interesting) discussion here: http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php and also here http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/01/label-alignment-in-long-forms-paper-prototyping-for-engineers.php

Comment: Thank you, that eyetracking research is very interesting. I'm responsible for ensuring our project meets WCAG 2 and that article is just what I need to convince one of our UE designers to change their thinking :) (and the article does conclude that if the label has to be to the left of the field, right aligned is far better than left aligned :) )

Comment: I do agree; but what about the new trend of placing the label inside the field? Some research in the eye tracking may be interesting on this too. I suppose it could be even better.

Comment: A few issues using the placeholder attribute as a label - 1) it's not WCAG compliant. 2) older browsers don't support placeholder. It can be simulated with JavaScript but if you have a requirement that JavaScript is to be used for progressive enhancement, this is not achievable without providing an alternative label for when javaScript is not available. Finally, if you use  the placeholder solution to label your fields, once the user has entered data into the field,  it's no longer possible to read the label. If I had free reign, my personal choice would be directly above the field.

Comment: Thank you. html in question already has responsive design: it adapts itself to any window width properly. What improvements can cssgrid.net add to it ? I havent noticed any. Based on your answer I understand that only way it to make all caption widths the same and all input div widths the same. Forms are created dynamically at runtime. How to calculate optimum caption and input div widths at runtime or is it possible to avoid hard coded values and force browser to find them itself ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, pure CSS solution for online form is NOT easy. Luckily, some brilient people in Wufoo have made some excellent CSS form that I can learn from. Their CSS based form online example:

Example page:
http://www.wufoo.com/examples/#eventregistration

Multiple column Form example:
https://examples.wufoo.com/forms/s7p7s5/

Answer (score 0):

To display children in a column orientation, flex box will work.

```
#_form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```