# How to replace fixed values in responsible form css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-ui

Responsible form is created using code below.
If window is resized, it resizes itself automatically, captions and input elements stay aligned.

It contains fixed values 210px, 75px, 100px, 120 px is css below.
Is it reasonable and if yes, how to remove/replace those fixed values with something other
like percents or em's ?

input, select elements and jquery-ui autocomplete with dropdown button are used.

```
<form class='ui-widget-content form-document'>

<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='nimi'>Customer name</label>
<span class='form-fullwidth'>
<input class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all form-autocomplete' name='nimi' value='Karu Org AS' ></input>
<button type='button' class='form-combobutton' tabindex=-1 ></button>
</span>
</div>

<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='Number'>Number</label>
<input class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all form-fullwidth' name='Number' />
</div>

<div class='form-field'>
<label class='form-label' for='payterm'>Pay term</label>
<span id='span_Maksetin1_tingimus' class='form-fullwidth'>
<select class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all form-fullwidth' name='payterm'>

<option value='' selected='selected'></option>
<option value='0'>0 days</option>
</select>
</span>
</div>

... lot of similar form-field divs
</form>
```

css:

```
.form-document
{
    padding: 0.5%;
}

.form-field
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 210px; /* label width + input field width */
}

.form-label
{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: smaller;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 75px;  /* determine by max caption width */
}

.form-fullwidth
{
    width: 120px; /* 210-5-75 */
}

.form-autocomplete
{
    width: 100px; /* 210-5-75-combobutton width*/
}


.form-combobutton
{
    height: 1.09em;
    margin: 0 0 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ok to me though I personally use ems in most cases.

You could also consider using a preprocessor like LESS if you want to use variables to avoid repetition. You can get LESS or SASS via nuget and there are zillions of tutorials out there.

Comment: I read from some tutorial that magic constants should removed from css files. preprocessor still leaves magic constants in css. Question asks how to replace them, eq. make widths as percents